# PHP XML serializer

Tags: php, xml, serialization, pear

Is there some php libraries which implement serialization of data to XML-format like `serialize()` and `unserialize()` (with restoring objects from XML) functions of objects with `private` and `protected` fields?

PEAR XML_Serializer works fine with *type hints* option, but it doen't deal with protected fields.

Comment: If PEAR XML_Serializer works fine maybe it's easy to add support for protected fields by using PHP 5.3's reflection? I can imagine this was not possible when the class was written, so probably adding a flag and extending the serialize / deserialize methods for fields could do it. It's available on github now, so might be easy to patch and keeping track of upstream changes: https://github.com/pear/XML_Serializer

Comment: @hakre Thank you very much, it took just 6 lines of code to patch XML_Serializer/XML_Unserializer classes for our project requirements!

Comment: I suggest you put the fork on github, too. so folks from pear can see this. can be very useful I would say. protected members can make sense in serialization (however this can be a corner-case and probably a smell). But sharing is good anyway.

Comment: @hakre I think this commit will be smelly, because in XML_Unserializer our code fills private and protected fields of the object in assumption that there are appropriate setters for every field (for example, for `private $_id;` there should be setter `public setId($id);` which sets `$_id` without any influence on other private variables).

Comment: Sure that can be, but in any case I would say it's worth to share. This can be turned into a flag and conditionally enabled. Or just the fork can be kept up-to date depending on needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping this is not considered spamming, but I've been working on a library that deals with serializing and deserialing objects from and to XML.

https://github.com/evert/sabre-xml/

However, it doesn't do exactly what you're asking. Every object you want to serialize needs to implement a `serializeXML` and `deserializeXML` method. In this method you can decide *exactly* what you need to implement.

If you do plan to use this, I would actually be happy to include the exact feature you want as a PHP 5.4 trait. Just send me a message (you can find my info on github).

Comment: Thank you very much, but we patched easily PEAR XML_Serializer classes  as hakre had suggested in his comment. We considered to use your way before the attempt to extend XML_Serializer functionality.

Comment: @Evert: As long as it is on topic and helpful and not spam and you do the disclosure this is normally not a problem here on the website. It's always nice to get feedback from developers who write libraries their own I would say, so this is more a win than anything else.

Answer (score 7):

The Symfony [Serializer Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) provides `serialize()` and `deserialize()` methods and supports multiple formats out of the box: XML, JSON, YAML...

It is included with Symfony but **you can use it even in a non Symfony project**, by installing it with composer:

```
composer require symfony/serializer
```

If you use the `ObjectNormalizer` as shown in the [documentation example](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#usage), don't forget to also install `symfony/property-access`.